# Calculus and tangents question

Tags: calculus

Find the x-coordinates of all the points on the curve $y = 2x^4 + 6x^3 + 3.5x^2 - 5x + \frac{3}{2}$ at which the tangent to the curve is parallel to the tangent at $(-1,\,6)$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  I've edited your post using $\rm\TeX$ (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.

Comment: Hi Dando, I have tried differentiating and I get 8x^3 + 18x^2 + 7x -5, but I'm stuck to work with the next part. Just blank and confused from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find the derivative at $x=-1$ to find the slope of the tangent line there. Then any parallel lines will have the same slope. So you want to solve $y'(x) = y'(-1)$.
$$ y' = 8x^3 + 18x^2 + 7x - 5 $$
$$ y'(-1) = -8 + 18 - 7 - 5 = -2 $$
Find where the derivative is $-2$ elsewhere 
$$ y'(x) = -2 $$

So solve $ -2 = 8x^3 + 18x^2 + 7x - 5 $ for $x$ to find the x points where $y$ is parallel.

*note:* the above cubic factors to $(x+1)(2x+3)(4x-1)=0$

Comment: so 8x^3 + 18x^2 + 7x -3 = 0, where we know that (x+1) is a factor, but what next?

Comment: just factoring. Divide out the factor of $(x+1)$ (via long or synthetic division) and factor the remaining quadratic as so: $8x^3 + 18x^2 + 7x - 3 = (x+1)(2x+3)(4x-1)=0$

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help, I understand now. Just got confused by the question ...

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the slope at the point say $$P(x_0,f(x_0))$$ must be the same like at the point $$P_1(-1,6)$$ thus we have to solve the equation
$$f'(x_0)=-2$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I get the final answer, but can someone proof check if what I am doing is correct. So from finding 8x^3 + 18x^2 + 7x -3 = 0, we know that one of the factors if (x+1). Then we get (x+1)(8x^2 + 10x -3). finding that quadratic leaves me to three values of x being x=-1, x=0.25, x= -3/2.

Comment: Yes that is correct.